# Want to find content difference between two text files with java

Tags: java

I have two text files,

- a.txt
- b.txt

Each text files contains some file paths. `b.txt` contains some more file paths than `a.txt`. I would like to determine which paths are added and which are removed from `a.txt` so that it corresponds to paths in `b.txt`.

For example,

abc.txt contains

```
E:\Users\Documents\hello\a.properties
E:\Users\Documents\hello\b.properties
E:\Users\Documents\hello\c.properties
```

and xyz.txt contains

```
E:\Users\Documents\hello\a.properties
E:\Users\Documents\hello\c.properties
E:\Users\Documents\hello\g.properties
E:\Users\Documents\hello\h.properties
```

Now how to find that g.prop and h.prop are added and b.prop is removed?

Could anyone explain how it is done? I could only find how to check for identical contents.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: you read first file content and store in a variable[list]  then read second one line by line and compare

Comment: Read both into sets and determine the intersection etc of the two sets. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)

Comment: as Lance Java says, store a's paths in a Set<String> A and b's paths in Set<String> B. Then, A intersection B are the common paths, B setdiff A is the set of paths that existed in B but do not exist in A and A setdiff B is the opposite.

Comment: Show the sample contents of both the file in question.

Comment: abc.txt contains "E:\Users\Documents\hello\a.properties E:\Users\Documents\hello\b.properties E:\Users\Documents\hello\c.properties"                                                         and xyz.txt contains "E:\Users\Documents\hello\a.properties E:\Users\Documents\hello\c.properties E:\Users\Documents\hello\g.properties E:\Users\Documents\hello\h.properties"                                                        now how to find that g.prop and h.prop are added and b.prop is removed .

Comment: @aswini i just added that to your original post, please delete those comments and edit the question to improve the formatting (e.g., is each path stored in a new line?)

Comment: yeah each path is written in new line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below code will serve your purpose irrespective of the content of the file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class Test {
        public Test(){
            System.out.println("Test.Test()");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            BufferedReader br1 = null;
            BufferedReader br2 = null;
            String sCurrentLine;
            List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
            br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test2.txt"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                list1.add(sCurrentLine);
            }
            while ((sCurrentLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                list2.add(sCurrentLine);
            }
            List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>(list1);
            tmpList.removeAll(list2);
            System.out.println("content from test.txt which is not there in test2.txt");
            for(int i=0;i<tmpList.size();i++){
                System.out.println(tmpList.get(i)); //content from test.txt which is not there in test2.txt
            }

            System.out.println("content from test2.txt which is not there in test.txt");

            tmpList = list2;
            tmpList.removeAll(list1);
            for(int i=0;i<tmpList.size();i++){
                System.out.println(tmpList.get(i)); //content from test2.txt which is not there in test.txt
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can directly copy paste code and give path of your file in two buffer reader and it will work. But basically i am assuming one line is one String and comparing it. See if it helps you

Answer (score 2):

The memory will be a problem as you need to load both files into the program.
I am using `HashSet` to ignore duplicates.Try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class FileReader1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String filename = "abc.txt";
        String filename2 = "xyz.txt";
        HashSet <String> al = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet <String> al1 = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet <String> diff1 = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet <String> diff2 = new HashSet<String>();
        String str = null;
        String str2 = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                al.add(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename2));
            while ((str2 = in.readLine()) != null) {
                al1.add(str2);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String str3 : al) {
            if (!al1.contains(str3)) {
                diff1.add(str3);
            }
        }
        for (String str5 : al1) {
            if (!al.contains(str5)) {
                diff2.add(str5);
            }
        }
        for (String str4 : diff1) {
            System.out.println("Removed Path: "+str4);
        }
        for (String str4 : diff2) {
            System.out.println("Added Path: "+str4);
        }


    }

}
```

Output:

```
Removed Path: E:\Users\Documents\hello\b.properties
Added Path: E:\Users\Documents\hello\h.properties
Added Path: E:\Users\Documents\hello\g.properties
```

Comment: thank you so much.. but here removed path is coming in between added paths.. why they can't be separated..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by added  or removed path? could you be more clear?

Comment: Check the update If you mean what I understand it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple do follow

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Path firstFile = Paths.get("/home/src/main/resources/a.txt");
        final Path secondFile = Paths.get("/home/src/main/resources/b.txt");
        final List<String> firstFileContent = Files.readAllLines(firstFile,
            Charset.defaultCharset());
        final List<String> secondFileContent = Files.readAllLines(secondFile,
            Charset.defaultCharset());

        System.out.println(diffFiles(firstFileContent, secondFileContent));
        System.out.println(diffFiles(secondFileContent, firstFileContent));
    }

    private static List<String> diffFiles(final List<String> firstFileContent,
        final List<String> secondFileContent) {
        final List<String> diff = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (final String line : firstFileContent) {
            if (!secondFileContent.contains(line)) {
                diff.add(line);
            }
        }
        return diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: With added line numbers: `diff.add((firstFileContent.indexOf(line) + 1) + " " + line);`.

Answer (score 0):

Compare files [Scanner and ArrayList]:

```
protected static void compareFiles(String firstFile, String secondFile)
        throws Exception {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(new File(firstFile));
    List<String> list1 = getScannerList(x);

    x = new Scanner(new File(secondFile));
    List<String> list2 = getScannerList(x);

    x.close();

    System.out.println("File Extras");
    printLnList(listExtras(list1, new ArrayList<String>(list2)));

    System.out.println("File Removals");
    printLnList(listExtras(list2, list1));  
}

protected static List<String> listExtras(List<String> list1,
        List<String> list2) throws Exception {      
    list2.removeAll(list1);
    return list2;
}

protected static List<String> getScannerList(Scanner sc) throws Exception {

    List<String> scannerList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (sc.hasNext())
        scannerList.add(sc.nextLine());

    return scannerList;
}

protected static void printLnList(List<String> list) {
    for (String string : list)
        System.out.println(string);
}
```

Program output:

```
File Extras
E:\Users\Documents\hello\g.properties
E:\Users\Documents\hello\h.properties
File Removals
E:\Users\Documents\hello\b.properties
```