# Compare two Unicode files and write output in third file

Tags: java, string, ubuntu, file-handling

I have two files. Both files have **equal** number of lines(1000 each). I have to compare these files and write difference in third file. Each **concurrent** line may have different number of words.

I have tried `diff` command in Ubuntu. but it Neither work well with Urdu nor giving required results.

I have tried and updated accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426187/want-to-find-content-difference-between-two-text-files-with-java) java code.

I am not posting code here question will become lengthy.

**Sample Input File One:**

Hence it is that is almost a definition of a gentleman to say he is one who never inflicts pain

This description is both refined and as far as it goes accurate He is mainly occupied in merely

**Sample Input File Two:**

Hence it is that is most a definition of gentleman to lay he is one who never infects pain

This description is both refine and far as it goes accurate He is mainly occupy in merely

**Required Out Put:**

almost   =>  most

say => lay

inflicts =>  infects

refined  => refine

as =>

occupied = occupy

Any Script / code / Software or command which can do the trick for me will be appreciated. I know Java and also have `Ubuntu 16.10` and `Windows 10`

If it is java code then I know file handling and have written file writing code.

**Note: Originally files are in Urdu. So its Unicode. I did not post Urdu as most of world don't understand it. I am comparing speech recognition results. File one is input file and file two is results after recognition.**

Comment: This is surprisingly complicated, if every line was the same length and words matched up it'd be trivial.  With the absence of some words... not so easy.  If there is `a b c d` and `a e d` as lines, would it show `b c => d`, or `b => e, c => `?

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/diff 
This website work something like that. Although it don't tell if word's absence.  Logic may be something like after and before word base.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick algorithm I put together

It looks for series of non-similar words to print, prioritizing similar length series

```
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
String lineA = "stuff and a few things";
String lineB = "stuff and maybe many things";

String[] a = lineA.split(" ");
String[] b = lineB.split(" ");
int counterA = 0;
int counterB = 0;

while(counterA < a.length && counterB < b.length)
{
    if(a[counterA].equals(b[counterB])) //check if next two elements are equal
    {
        counterA++;
        counterB++;
        continue;
    }

    //search from array a looking for matches in array b
    int aStart = -1;
    int aStop = -1;
    for(aStart = counterA; aStart < a.length && aStop == -1; aStart++)
        for(int i = counterB; i < b.length && aStop == -1; i++)
            if(a[aStart].equals(b[i]))
                aStop = i;
    if(aStop == -1) //no matches, select rest of both lists
    {
        aStart++; //need to inc start one extra time
        aStop = b.length;
    }

    //search from array b looking for matches in array a
    int bStart = -1;
    int bStop = -1;
    for(bStart = counterB; bStart < b.length && bStop == -1; bStart++)
        for(int i = counterA; i < a.length && bStop == -1; i++)
            if(b[bStart].equals(a[i]))
                bStop = i;
    if(bStop == -1) //no matches, select rest of both lists
    {
        bStart++; //need to inc one extra time
        bStop = a.length;
    }

    //find which one is more similar
    int aDist = Math.abs((--aStart - counterA) - (aStop - counterB)); //aStart and bStart are incremented 1 too many times
    int bDist = Math.abs((--bStart - counterB) - (bStop - counterA));

    if(aDist < bDist) //a's findings are a better match
    {
        String out = "";
        for(int i = counterA; i < aStart; i++)
            out += a[i] + " ";
        out += "=> ";
        for(int i = counterB; i < aStop; i++)
            out += b[i] + " ";
        out = out.substring(0, out.length() - 1); //remove last space
        output.add(out);
        counterA = aStart;
        counterB = aStop;
    }
    else //b's findings are a better match
    {
        String out = "";
        for(int i = counterA; i < bStop; i++)
            out += a[i] + " ";
        out += "=> ";
        for(int i = counterB; i < bStart; i++)
            out += b[i] + " ";
        out = out.substring(0, out.length() - 1); //remove last space
        output.add(out);
        counterA = bStop;
        counterB = bStart;
    }
}

System.out.println(output);
```

In this example, it prints "[a few => maybe many]" ([]'s from the list)

Run this on each line of the files, and it should give a fairly good diff

Comment: Why it is printing -1 for some lines ?

Comment: What is on the line?  It should always have a "=>" in the line if there's differing text

Comment: String it in Urdu. I think you will not understand it. Its doing fine for some lines. but for some lines it simply print -1;

Comment: Is there a -1 on the line?  Can the other parts of your code print -1?  Is it just -1 without any other spacing or characters?

Comment: String lineB = "کو اپنے اجلاس میں فیصله کیا تھا که هر سال تءیس مارچ کو قرارداد لاهور قرارداد پاکستان کے حوالے سے یوم پاکستان منایا جاءے گا مسلم لیگ کا  ";
              String lineA = "وه اپنی اصلاح میں فیصله کیا تھا که هر سال اکتیس مارچ کو قرارداد لاهور قرارداد پاکستان کے حوالے سے انهوں نے پاکستان بنایا جاءے گا مسلم لیگ ق ";

Comment: Copy these strings as it is and then run.

Comment: Interesting, getting an out of bounds error (-1), will look into it

Comment: @ALI Fixed the issue, it wasn't finding the different last words correctly